# Access a contract inside a contract from truffle

Tags: node.js, solidity, truffle

I have this code:

```
contract A{}
contract B{
    A public a;
}
```

Can I use truffle to access to a like

```
B b = new B(); b.a.function1();
```

Comment: Check this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26028/how-to-access-a-token-instance-created-by-another-smart-contract-constructor